# Not able to fetch App Configurations Policy from Microsoft Intune in android app

Tags: android, azure, intune

The requirement is to create a key-value pair and add to the app configuration policy at portal side.
ex. endpointURL : "some-value"

The Android app should be configured in a way that it should access this configurations in the app and should be able to set  the endpointURL in app.

I followed below steps  [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-android#enabling-mam-targeted-configuration-for-your-android-applications-optional) to Support App configuration policies in the app :

Added the permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

**I have pasted below code inside LoginServiceImpl.java where I am setting endpoint URL.**

```
MAMAppConfigManager configManager = MAMComponents.get(MAMAppConfigManager.class);
        String identity = "<user-name>@mobileinfy.onmicrosoft.com";
//       
        MAMAppConfig appConfig = configManager.getAppConfig(identity);  //<= this line returning null.
        Log.i("App Config Data = ",(appConfig == null ? "null" : appConfig.getFullData().toString()));
        String valueToUse = null;
        if (appConfig.hasConflict("endpointURL")) // <=So getting Exception at this line NullPointerException
         {
            List<String> values = appConfig.getAllStringsForKey("ServerUrl");
            for (String value : values) {

                    valueToUse = value;

            }
        } else {
            valueToUse = appConfig.getStringForKey("endpointURL ", MAMAppConfig.StringQueryType.Any);
        }
        Log.i("Found value " , valueToUse);
```

I followed the steps [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-configuration-policies-use-android) to add app configuration policies in Intune portal

**Steps that I followed to test app :**
1.Installed company portal and logged in using our Intune account id:@mobileinfy.onmicrosoft.com
2.  Installed app using android studio
3.  Tried to log in -> app crashed. (as exception occurred.)

**Another set of steps to test app :**
1.  Generated apk -> uploaded to intune portal
2.  Installed company portal and logged in using our Intune account id:  ayush14197@mobileinfy.onmicrosoft.com
3.  Assigned app config policies to this app and synced.
4.  Tried installing app from company portal app.
5.  Tried to log in -> app crashed. (as exception occurred.)

Could you please help me to get this issue resolved?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting two issues that aren't well documented in the Intune APP SDK docs:

1. `MAMAppConfigManager.getAppConfig` can return null if no app config data has been receieved for the user. The example given should be performing a null check on `appConfig`.
2. To receive app config, the user must have MAM policy targeted for at least one app for app config to be delivered. This is mentioned, but only on the [Managed Browser app config page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-configuration-managed-browser#create-a-protected-browser-app-configuration) even though it applies to all apps.

I hope that helps -- these documentation issues should be fixed in the next release of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for answering bannus. I already selected my  lob app in targeted app. Can we selected anyone from the list?eg: outlook or browser. Is it needed to associate app for Managing App config?

Comment: Tried the steps in your link, but no success.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which app is targeted, as long as you have at least one targeted at the user. After you sign in to the app, can you [collect Company Portal logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-user-help/send-logs-to-your-it-admin-by-email-android) and email them to wintunedroidfbk@microsoft.com?